# Headphones not showing up in playback devices menu - windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, speakers

I recently upgraded my computer to windows 10 from windows 8.1, and I'd like to set my audio output quality to studio, and apply the same audio enhancements that I used on windows 8.1 .

I can't do this, because my computer isn't displaying the headphones as a separate from the built in speakers in the "playback devices" menu. When I plug in the headphones it tells me that I've plugged something into the audio jack and the output switches over to the headphones exclusively, but I still can't see them listed.

My other windows 10 machine does this too, but I was able to get around this by applying the enhancements and the quality switch directly to the built in speakers.

Any idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do;

Plug in your headphones

Right-click the speaker icon in the system tray and go to 'Sounds'

In the playback tab, right-click the default speakers and select show disabled devices and show disconnected devices. Your headphones should now appear here.

Right-click the headphones and select 'enable'

If you need images, this is a tutorial: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-auto-adjust-volume-for-headphones-in-windows-10/

**Disclaimer:** I'm the editor for the blog I've linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a necro post.. but it might help somebody else.

I had the same issue after reinstalling Windows 10 recently.  The problem for me was that it installed "old" version of Windows 10 and I didn't know it.  Using update to current version of Windows added in the ability to choose between different speakers and headphones in the playback devices menu.  That was included in the Anniversary update I believe.

I had spent hours trying to research why I wouldn't have those options in the drop down menu of playback devices.  Hopefully that's just your issue too as it's an easy fix if so.

Comment: Helpful answers and insights are always welcome on questions that haven't been closed. The main purpose of Stack Exchange sites is to generate as much useful information for as many things as possible. "Necro posting" isn't taboo on Stack Exchange sites like you may be accustomed to on most BBSs; there's even [a badge for it](https://superuser.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)! As long as you're researching and putting effort into your answers, your contributions will always be welcome.